# ionic 2 themeablebrowser icons are not displaying

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am trying to open links using themeable browser plugin. I managed to make it work but I couldn't get the icons displayed? I tried changing hex values but it didn't help. Below is my code,

```
navigate() {
let options = {
 statusbar: {
     color: '#ffffff'
 },
 toolbar: {
     height: 44,
     color: '#2e6abf'
 },
 title: {
     color: '#ffffff',
     showPageTitle: true
 },
 backButton: {
     image: 'back',
     imagePressed: 'back_pressed',
     align: 'left',
     event: 'backPressed'
 },
 forwardButton: {
     image: 'forward',
     imagePressed: 'forward_pressed',
     align: 'left',
     event: 'forwardPressed'
 },
 closeButton: {
     image: 'close',
     imagePressed: 'close_pressed',
     align: 'left',
     event: 'closePressed'
 },
 customButtons: [
     {
         image: 'share',
         imagePressed: 'share_pressed',
         align: 'right',
         event: 'sharePressed'
     }
 ],
 menu: {
     image: 'menu',
     imagePressed: 'menu_pressed',
     title: 'Test',
     cancel: 'Cancel',
     align: 'right',
     items: [
         {
             event: 'helloPressed',
             label: 'Hello World!'
         },
         {
             event: 'testPressed',
             label: 'Test!'
         }
     ]
 },
 backButtonCanClose: true
};

let browser = new ThemeableBrowser('http://sparklms.com', '_blank', options);

  }
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: i am also having some issue in ionic 2 themeablebroswer. Can you help me out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43887323/ionic-2-themeable-browser-error

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to import the images *natively* first.
The [README](https://github.com/initialxy/cordova-plugin-themeablebrowser) for the project mentions:

> One thing to note is that all image resources reference to **native resource bundle**. So all images need to be imported to native project first. In case of Android, the image name will be looked up under R.drawable. eg. If image name is hello_world, R.drawable.hello_world will be referenced.

Alternatively they offer the possibility to use the `wwwImage` parameter instead of the `image` one (then just dropping your images in `www/assets/` folder).

```
backButton: {
    wwwImage: 'images/back.png',
    wwwImagePressed: 'images/back_pressed.png',
    wwwImageDensity: 2,
    align: 'left',
    event: 'backPressed'
}
```

Comment: So big question if we use image for all of our buttons in the toolbar and we want native ones that are provided by ionicons, how do we go about doing that? Because right now if image for backButton is image: 'back', nothing shows up which I understand why, what I do not understand is how to get those native icons added to project files that work for all platforms. Any help with that?

Comment: @NoahTanenholtz I'm not sure there is a direct way to do that. Ionicons are "native" to ionic but in the case of `themeablebrowser` you'd still have to link them somehow (either using the way described above or by adding them to Xcode https://github.com/initialxy/cordova-plugin-themeablebrowser#import-native-images). One way to achieve what you want would be to add the icon files you want to use (you can find them here: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionicons/tree/master/src/svg) to the image folder of your project and link them the way described here.

Comment: I tried also using wwwImage instead which works but shows the icon on the toolbar zoomed in by a lot. The icon is an x for 'closeButton' but its shown zoomed in to the center. I tried changing the density but that didn't work. Should I just manually change the pixel size in a photo editor or do something else?